# Lose focus of current activity on device orientation change

Tags: android

Mi main activity is a TabActivity that launches an intent TabGroup activity, this tabGroup starts a child activity, this child activity is a Listview with several options.
And now, if you select some option from the listview and change the device orientation, I lose focus from the current activity because the oncreate() from the TabGroup is called, there is any way to prevent this?
Many thanks for the help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity gets shut down and restarted on orientation change.

use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` to store the selected option and restore that selection in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

i.e.

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
bundle.putInt("selected", listView.getSelectedItemPosition());
}


onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
if (bundle.containsKey("selected")) {
listView.setSelection(bundle.getInt("selected"));
}
```

Comment: Hi djg, I'll try to implement this, but if each element of the list(a GridView actually) launch another activity?
I'm launching each activity by setOnItemClickListener.
If I do MyGridView.setSelection(value from onSaveInstanceState), setOnItemClickListener is called automatically?
Many thanks.

Comment: I think you are asking if calling setSelection(..) will trigger the OnItemClick event and notify your listener.  I'm assuming this is undesirable in the onCreate(..) call.  If so, can you call setSelection(..) before setOnItemClickListener(..)?  Please add more details if my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: During touch mode setSelection doen't work :(, you need to use the click listeners. By then I use a variable to store the current selection and pass that variable to onSaveInstanceState(), It works wonders :).
I can't find a way to launch a click event manually, and outside onCreate()

Many many Thanks for the help.